# Word randomization in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random

In Actionscript, I'm trying to find a way to produce strings and string variables which spit out different text each time they're brought up. To purely visualize:

```
var text:String "Red||Blue"; //Whenever the variable is called, it's either Red or Blue

textoutput("You spot a grey||black cat."); //A function equivalent of the same issue
```

I can produce a function which does this effect, but it seems a variable cannot be a function, as far as I can tell.

I've considered array variables, but I have no idea how to use an array to spit out a single entry when the variable is called, and I don't know how to make this work for a string that isn't a variable -- assuming I can get away with a single system that works for both situations.

**Edit**

To expand upon the issue expressed in Batman's answer, using his result on a variable produces a result that 'sticks' to whichever it randomly chooses. Example:

```
var shoes:String = grabRandomItem("Red shoes||Crimson shoes");

trace("You have " + shoes + ".") //Whichever result is chosen it stays that way.
```

Moreover, I may want to change this variable to something else that is entirely not-random:

```
var secondshoes:String = "Blue shoes";

function newshoes():
{
     shoes = secondshoes;
}
```

Comment: container objects like arrays are indispensable in coding with any language. If you plan on becoming a coder you need to start using them and be familiar with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to do this, but to align with the way you'd like to do it, here is the simplest way to accomplish this:

```
//populate your string: (remove the word private if using timeline code)
private var text_:String = "Red||Blue||Green||Yellow";

//create a getter to use a function like a property
function get text():String {
    //create an array by splitting the text on instances of ||
    var arr:Array = text_.split("||");
    //return a random element of the array you just made
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

trace(text);
```

---

Even better, create a common function to parse your string:

```
function grabRandomItem(str:String):String {
    var arr:Array = str.split("||");
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

//make a getter variable that regenerates everytime it's called.
function get label():String {
    return "You spot a " + grabRandomItem("grey||black||blue||red||purple") + " cat";
}

trace(label); //anytime you access the label var, it will re-generate the randomized string

trace(label);
trace(label);
trace(label);
//  ^^ should have different results
```

---

Of course, this way I think only works best if the text comes from user input.  If you are hard coding the text into the app, you might as well just create it in an array directly as show in [another answer you have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31392799/1457439) as there's less overhead involved that way.

Comment: This answer was very helpful, the second example in particular is compact and easy to operate.

When attempting to apply this function to a variable, the result I get -- while still random -- remains permanent. Is there a way to get around this?

The array route is tricky by virtue of the variables I'm dealing with, this variable can be changed by other variables, and it's not always a selection of multiple types of text, and I'm a little hesitant to make all string variables all arrays, all the time.

Comment: can you update/append to your question the code you're using? It's hard to understand without seeing the code you're trying

Comment: If you want to re-randomize, you'll have to use `getRandomItem` again and rebuild the string.  You'll need to architect your app in a way all your text get's regenerated if one of your random elements needs to be refreshed/re-randomized.    Just create helper function or make your text var a getter and rebuild the string there

Comment: I should've guessed as much... Again, thank you for you're help!

Comment: You could write a text parser that somehow binds vars to text field and replaces instances of something like `{{blue||purple||red}}` with one of the values, but it seems like un-needed overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You want a random value from a list of possible values.  Rather than call the variable, you can reference it dynamically...

```
function random(low:Number=0, high:Number=1):Number {
    /* Returns a random number between the low and high values given. */
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
}

var options:Array = ["red", "blue", "grey", "black"];
trace("You spot a " + options[random(0, options.length-1)] + " cat.")

//You spot a black cat.
```

Alternatively, you can use a function in place of a variable to remove the inline logic...

```
function catColor():String { return options[random(0, options.length-1)]; }
trace("You found a " + catColor() + " key.")

// You found a red key.
```

Or generalize it to a generic function with arguments.

```
var options:Object = {
    "cat":["grey", "black"],
    "key":["gold", "silver"],
    "door":["blue", "red", "green"]
}

function get(item:String):String {
    return options[item][random(0, options[item].length-1)];
}

trace("You found a " + get("door") + " door.")

// You found a green door.
```

Comment: @Marohen - This is also a good way to go (as per the last sentence in my answer) +1